# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay not invoked when called indirectly via a block but is otherwise

Tags: ios

I'm doing a few experiments with background processing during a phone call and have found that I cannot get a performSelector:withObject:afterDelay call to fire if it was invoked indirectly from within a block, but it will fire if called directly.

This code shows what I mean:

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (void) sausages
{
    NSLog(@"*************Sausages");
    [self performSelector:@selector(sausages) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
}
- (void) sausages2
{
    NSLog(@"*************Sausages 2");
    [self performSelector:@selector(sausages2) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
        [self sausages2];

        MyAppDelegate __weak *weakSelf = self;
        [self.callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call)
         {
        if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
             {
                 NSLog(@"Incomming");
                 [weakSelf sausages];
             }
         }];
```

When I run this code and switch the app to the background then the sausages2 method gets triggered every 10 seconds (the app has the location background mode not shown in the code snippet).

When I make a phone call to the device and answer it then during the call the sausages2 method still continues to trigger every 10 seconds however the sausages method only triggers once. Why is that? Why isn't the sausages method continually being invoked during the call but the sausages2 method is?

Comment: possibly you need your sausages function to perform the selector on the main queue?  just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `setCallEventHandler` is undoubtedly running asynchronously, and you cannot use `performSelector` with a delay from an asynchronous block that runs on anything but the main queue (because it needs a `NSRunLoop`).

It's easier to use `dispatch_after`, which won't suffer from this issue. For example, if you want to call `someMethod` on the main queue after ten seconds, you can do:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self someMethod];
});
```

Or, if you want it to run on some background queue:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self someMethod];
});
```

---

Having said that, it looks like you want to call this method repeatedly, so I might just be inclined to use a `NSTimer` or a dispatch source timer, rather than having the method call itself after 10 seconds. For example, if starting this timer from the main queue, you'd define a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

And then if starting this from the main queue, it would be as simple as:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(someMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

If starting this timer from your completion block, you may have to explicitly schedule the timer on the main runloop:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(someMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

And the `someMethod` would be defined to take the `NSTimer` as a parameter:

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, timer);
}
```

By the way, when doing a repeating timer, remember to `invalidate` the timer when, for example, the view disappears, to avoid a strong reference cycle:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self.timer invalidate];
}
```